# In to_crs of GeoPandas, init proj4 string works, but new style doesn't

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas

I wanted to unify crs into WGS 84, so based on
"[Manually specifying the CRS](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projections.html#manually-specifying-the-crs)"
I tried `gdf.to_crs('epsg:4326')`, but error occurs.
I want to know why the old proj4 style `gdf.to_crs({'init':'epsg:4326'})` works, why not the recommended `gdf.to_crs('epsg:4326')`. I used python 3.8.1 32bit, geopandas 0.7.0 and pyproj 2.5.0.

```
import geopandas

gdf=geopandas.read_file('note/map/bnd_emd_2012/BND_ADM_EMD_2012.shp')    
gdf.crs
```

```
<Projected CRS: PROJCS["PCS_ITRF2000_TM",GEOGCS["GCS_ITRF_2000",DA ...>
Name: PCS_ITRF2000_TM
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- [east]: Easting (metre)
- [north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Coordinate Operation:
- name: unnamed
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: International Terrestrial Reference Frame 2000
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

```
gdf1=gdf.to_crs({'init':'epsg:4326'})
```

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py", line 55
    return _prepare_from_string(" ".join(pjargs))
FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method. When making the change, be mindful of axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6
```

```
gdf1.crs
```

```
<Geographic 2D CRS: +init=epsg:4326 +type=crs>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- lon[east]: Longitude (degree)
- lat[north]: Latitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

```
gdf2=gdf.to_crs('epsg:4326')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    gdf2=gdf.to_crs('epsg:4326')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 564, in to_crs
    geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 436, in to_crs
    transformer = Transformer.from_crs(self.crs, crs, always_xy=True)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyproj\transformer.py", line 319, in from_crs
    _Transformer.from_crs(
  File "pyproj\_transformer.pyx", line 311, in pyproj._transformer._Transformer.from_crs
pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: Error creating Transformer from CRS.: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create_operations: geodeticCRS not found)
```

```
gdf2.crs
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    gdf2.crs
NameError: name 'gdf2' is not defined
```

Comment: That's an interesting case (as the code looks correct). Are you able to share the Shapefile? (or at least the content of the .prj file, that might be enough to investigate it)

Comment: Thank you for improving the readability and showing interest. The shapefile is here. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1Y50qcsV8Na3BEnz7vSntKgaRHU6_Xl91

Comment: It may be about python! I tried in python 3.7 x64 and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reported this as a bug here: https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/549

In the meantime, you can keep using the deprecated "{'init':'epsg:4326'}" syntax a bit longer (and ignore the warning for now).
Alternatively, you can use the following workaround to read the CRS directly from the .prj file (avoiding going through GDAL):

```py
gdf = geopandas.read_file('note/map/bnd_emd_2012/BND_ADM_EMD_2012.shp')    

with open("note/map/bnd_emd_2012/BND_ADM_EMD_2012.prj") as prj_file:
    crs = prj_file.read()

gdf.crs = crs

gdf2 = gdf.to_crs('epsg:4326')
```